# .htaccess not taking effect in php project

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp, .htaccess

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and am currently creating an api using php. I added an `.htaccess` file which SHOULD redirect any 404 pages back to my index.php. I am asking this in askubuntu because I believe it may be an issue with my apache configurations. I went into my `000-default` file in `/etc/apace2/sites-available` and modified the:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

I also modified my `apache2.conf` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to look like this:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

This is the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

I tried to write something like "THIS SHOULD ERROR" but when I went to reload the browser I did not get a 500 error as expected but still go the 400 error so this tells me that my `.htaccess` file is not being hit.

After modifying any apache or system files I did run

`sudo systemctl restart apache2` but no dice.

Not sure what else to modify at this point. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Presumably your `.htaccess` file is located at `/var/www/html/.htaccess`, which is the defined `DocumentRoot`? What about `/etc/apace2/sites-enabled`? Are you using vHosts? You shouldn't have to touch the main server config (ie. `apache2.conf`), unless you are specifically just configuring a single server (no vHosts). `AllowOverride` should be set as `None` for the `<Directory />` container.

Comment: @MrWhite I have an .htaccess in my ```/var/www/html/``` with the same rules and conditions. I also am using an ```.htaccess``` file locally in my php project. Could the issue be that my php project is located at ```/Desktop/Projects``` directory? Does it have to be in my ```/var/www/html/``` to work properly?

Comment: "Could the issue be that my php project is located at /Desktop/Projects directory?" - How is that supposed to work, given the config above? How is your PHP project being called? "Does it have to be in my /var/www/html/ to work properly?" - Well, that is probably where Apache is expecting to find you files - although this information is not stated in your question. (?)

Comment: @MrWhite I moved my php project into ```var/www/html``` and the .htaccess is still not taking effect

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem isn't that your .htaccess is being ignored but rather that mod_rewrite isn't enabled.  Try `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and restart Apache2.

Comment: I ran the command and got ```Module rewrite already enabled``` and restarted apache, still nothing. Would it matter that I am running the php project locally using ```php -S localhost:8889``` ?

Comment: @PA-GW If you are running your PHP project using `php -S ...` (ie. PHP's built-in webserver) then you are not using Apache. PHP's built-in webserver does not use `.htaccess`.

Comment: @MrWhite can you point me to a resource of how to set up vhosting using apache and the ```/var/www/html``` folder. I am using php built in webserver which is the wrong way. Sorry about that.